# C++ Chess board design and smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, chess, smart-pointer

I wrote a [Chess engine](https://github.com/RomainGoussault/Jeepov/tree/master/Deepov) in Java and I am porting it over to C++. I am new to C++.

### The idea:

I have a **Board** object which holds a 2-dimensionnal array of **Piece** objects. Queen, Rook, Bishop, etc are subclasses of Piece. They all have a method getPossibleMoves(). Therefore they need to have a reference to the board to be able to generate the possible moves.

### The implementation:

**Board class:**

```
class Board
{
public:
    using PiecePtr = std::shared_ptr<Piece>;
    std::array<std::array<PiecePtr, BOARD_SIZE>, BOARD_SIZE> myPieces;
};
```

**Piece class:**

```
class Piece
{
public:
    std::weak_ptr<Board> myBoard
};
```

I used shared_ptr and weak_ptr because the Board can/should exist whitout Pieces. Is this approach correct?

**Note**: I know this OOP approch to represent the chess board is not the best for performance. Other approaches ([Bitboards](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Bitboards) for instance) will be more efficient.

Comment: I have removed the constructors and methods in both classes for clarity.

Comment: Pieces without a board are useless. What do you mean with "they are way faster than my solution`?

Comment: I re-wrote that part. What I mean is that in a performance point of view my OOP approach to represent the board is going to be slower than other representations (like bitboards). But I don't care much about performance right now.

Comment: you should care about performance right now. NOW is the time to care about performance, when fundamental choices can have significant impact. Later, you're into the realm of micro optimisations that aren't worth it, when you've made the wrong decision that had a big impact early on and deliberately so...

Comment: "OOP approch to represent the chess board is not the best for performance" --- sounds like you are doing micro optimization.

Comment: My plan is to use Bitboards at a later stage, when I will be more confident with C++. Now I am just trying to port over my Java project into C++. When I say I don't care about performance, I should have said: I don't want sacrifice design over performance and I know that with this OOP approach the performance is going to be poor compared to bitboard. And I know that I will use bitboards in a near future.

Comment: @jwenting no, it is not. Optimizations are done at the end, when the bottle necks are identified.

Comment: @BЈовић no, when you identify a massive difference in potential performance during the design phase like this, or KNOW that one implementation will be far more efficient than another, you take the most efficient solution directly and save yourself a lot of work afterwards. Only fools implement something that they KNOW is bad and then afterwards try to change it around, chipping away at minor details, in order to try to get it to perform a fraction better when they could have prevented having to do all that work had they paid attention at the beginning.

Comment: @jwenting I'd be inclined to agree, if your scope is to write a program meant to be used in production.  If the scope is to *learn*, I think it is far more valuable to understand why one way is more efficient than another, hence you must crawl before you can walk.

Comment: @jwenting I am not sure how can you say such thing to such poorly formed question. How do you know that using weak_ptr is going to cause performance problems? What he asks is an implementation choice, not a design choice.

Comment: @BЈовић anything that's pointers to objects will incur a performance penalty, you're getting a lot of method calls, as compared to a bitboard. It's also going to use a lot more memory which, while less critical now as when I learned programming, is still not something to just discard (and remember, it takes time to access things in memory...).

Comment: @jwenting How did you get all that from such a vague question? Still, what you suggested sounds like a micro optimization.

Comment: @BЈовић I would argue that micro optimizations are those, where you change how things are done without changing the design of the program, what jwenting is suggesting, is changing the design of the program. That cannot be done in later stages of implementation without rewriting large parts of the program. Those decisions need to be done at design phase.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489

Answer (score 4):

This is a case of premature over-design.

The pieces don't need a pointer to the board.  Just pass the board to the 'generateMoves' method.  You don't even need objects for the individual chessmen.  All pawns are alike, so you only need one Pawn instance.

Also, by the laws of chess, there is a game state that is also needed to correctly generate moves.  Pawns can capture e.p. but only after a previous two-square advance.  A king can castle with a rook but not if either has previously moved.

My suggestion is to forget all the class design stuff.  Start with a single ChessGame class with two methods: generateMoves and makeMove.  Write it test-first.  Start by only having two kings on the board.  Then add the different kinds of chessmen one at a time.  Extract classes as you find it convenient.

Answer (score 0):

A small "being there, done that" suggestion... migrating my chess engine from a [0x88 board representation](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/0x88) to bitboard was **relatively** simple. Obtaining a performance improvement was way harder than I expected.

The fact is that you can have a wonderful design for your board/piece class, perfect modularity, minimum dependencies among classes... but it's sure that you must have arranged your evaluation logic depending on what you can do fast or slow (and this is linked to board representation).

Changing the board representation will trigger changes in the static evaluation logic: that's complex, time consuming and risky.

Moreover, while you change the evaluation logic, you discover that some search extensions aren't needed anymore or that you need a better quiescence search.

Eventually you could have a completely different player.

So you can start with a "temporary" board representation but everything should be done bearing in mind the final representation (strong/weak points of a representation you are not using could be unexpected).

---

Your implementation is the typical Team/Members relationship.
The Team object (the board) will have pointers to its Members (the pieces) and the members will also have a back pointer to their Team object.

So `weak_ptr` is used to break the dependency cycle: the "owner" use `shared_ptr` and the "owned" use a `weak_ptr` to its parent and convert it temporarily to `shared_ptr` when it needs access to its parent.

So, from this point of view, it's a correct implementation.

However the `getPossibleMoves()` function will need the piece position to perform its task.

The function could find out the position scanning the board but this would slow down the move generation. To avoid data redundancy you shouldn't store the coordinates inside `Piece` and `getPossibleMoves()` will need two arguments:

```
std::list<Move> ThePiece::getPossibleMoves(unsigned row, unsigned column)
{
  // ...
}

// ...
Board b;
// ...
auto moves = b[row][column]->getPossibleMoves(row, column);
```

Now why not remove the `myBoard` injected dependency from `Piece` and add one more argument to `getPossibleMoves`?

```
std::list<Move> ThePiece::getPossibleMoves(const Board &b, unsigned row, unsigned column)
{
  // ...
}
```

After this change the shared_ptr aren‘t required anymore... along this way we‘re going to completely change the design.

Answer (score -1):

Please review the background and use cases for weak_ptr. I don’t think this is one of them.

weak_ptr is typically used for as a cache. The owner of the weak_ptr must be ok with the weak_ptr being null. If the weak_ptr is null, the owner can adapt by constructing a new instance or otherwise operating differently.

In your case, a Piece cannot operate without a Board. The weak_ptr should be a smart_ptr.

I would go farther and say that you should not be using pointers at all. The entire system is well defined without any pointers. Try an entirely value based design. For example, the Board for the pieces could be a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: `weak_ptr` isn't being used improperly.  You might be confusing yourself with a weak pointer in Java, which only points to an object until the next garbage collection (and is therefore truly unstable).  `weak_ptr` just means that it doesn't interfere with the destruction of referenced object if the owner destroys it.  In this case, it is used to provide a reference, but not *ownership* of the board in each piece.

Comment: A weak_ptr is valid until the owning of the shared_ptr is deleted. If the board is deleted then the weak_ptr of Piece is no longer valid, i.e. the weak_ptr will fail to lock. That sounds like a cache to me. What would Piece do if the Board is deleted?

Comment: @BillDorr First of all: a shared ptr will cause circular dependencies that would lead to memory leak. Secondly, Pieces don't own the board so a shared pointer would express incorrect ownership. Technically, the piece could also store raw pointer, but then, if it somehow outlived the board it references, there would no way to detect that piece tries to reference incorrect pointer.

Comment: +1 using references, might be better then using smart pointers in this case

Comment: @UldisK, the circular dependencies is a good point. On your second point, shared_ptr does not indicated ownership. That’s kind of the point of shared_ptr. shared_ptr often indicates lack of ownership.

Comment: @BillDoor shared pointer indicates shared ownership. Lack of ownership means that you have no control over when object is destroyed, shared pointer gives you this control..weak pointer doesn't.